# $.getScript, possible to give included script an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, getscript

Via jquery's $.getScript method, can you give the included script a DOM id?

So generated code should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="xxxxxx" src="..."></script>
```

I know I could probably just document.write that line myself, but $.getScript must be there for a reason right? (cross browser compatibility, etc?)

Comment: document.write would be used before the DOM is ready. Usually jQuery methods are called after the DOM is ready. You probably meant you could just use `document.createElement("script")`

Comment: Out of curiousity what is the purpose of adding an ID to a dynamically loaded script?

Comment: @jamietre ... to dynamically UNload it later! ;-D

Comment: Why would you do that? What purpose does it serve? The script will already have executed. It won't have any effect on objects that have been created.  http://jsfiddle.net/ueFn3/  If you want to free memory, this isn't how to do it.

Comment: I'm using it to load a third party javascript, and in the source they seem to reference their own script by the id, that's why I needed to set it. I've now gone ahead and used the same snippet that google analytics uses (async) (no jquery)

Comment: Bizarre. I can't imagine why that would ever be necessary. It's not actually referencing "itself", it's just referencing some text between two script tags. Sounds like some kind of atrocious hack.

Comment: I've just taken a look, it seems to reference it to get a hold of the src attribute, so that it can look at ? query parameters (via regex.test).. Can't it just look at window.location itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has maybe been answered/discussed before here: [Why call $.getScript instead of using the <script> tag directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392884/why-call-getscript-instead-of-using-the-script-tag-directly).

getScript allows you to dynamically load a script in situations where it's either desirable to delay the loading of the script, in situations where you want to get a status callback on when the script has been loaded or in situations where you couldn't use a script tag.

getScript has some downsides in that it's subject to the same-origin policy whereas a script tag is not.

If have seen other web pages put an ID on a script tag (smugmug.com), but I've also seen that flagged as non-standard when testing standard's compliance.  It seems to work and be used by others, but I'm guessing it isn't standard.