# Load external script using getScript shows undefined

Tags: jquery

I was trying to get the external JS file in my HTML using `$.getScript`. However it is returning `undefined`.

Then I tried with `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` that also shows the same, `undefined`.

```js
$(function() {
  $.getScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    alert(data); // undefined
    alert(textStatus); // Success
    alert(jqxhr.status); // 200
    alert("Load was performed.");
  });
});
```

Is there any other way we can load the external script?

Comment: you can use a script tag, like the rest of the world

Comment: you are loading a jquery instance using jquery, why?

Comment: Are you hitting [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) issues?  Is the script you're loading hosted on the same domain that the script is running on?

Comment: @madalinivascu I was just trying a sample url. Actual url is different one.

Comment: @freefaller: We are just including the script right? In that case does this same origin matters? Anyway, url is loading when I hit on browser.

Comment: Using a `<script>` tag does not have same-origin constraints... using `getScript` does (although the documentation doesn't actually state it).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4392906/930393)

Comment: @madalinivascu: I used the script tag first. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://myjs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.myfunctionInMyjs();
  </script> ` - like this. But getting window.myfunctionInMyjs is not a function. Means the script is not loaded right?

Comment: means you need a document ready statement so you execute the code **after all the content has loaded**

Answer (score 0):

After asking the following question in comments...

> Are you hitting same origin policy issues? Is the script you're loading hosted on the same domain that the script is running on?

... and the response from the OP...

> We are just including the script right? In that case does this same origin matters? Anyway, url is loading when I hit on browser

... leads me to believe the OP is trying to load script from a different domain.

Using the `<script>` tag does not have [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) constraints, meaning you can load a script from anywhere.

However, the jquery [`getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) functionality **does** have the constraint (despite it not being mentioned in the documentation), meaning you can **only** load script from the same domain (unless you have [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) set up).

Comment: Thanks. But I just checked. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin * `. Also there is no CORS errors/warmings in the console.

Comment: Just to confirm... where are the headers set?  They must be on the external domain

Comment: Yes it is on the external domain

Comment: Fair enough - then I'm unable to explain what you're getting, sorry.